# How get GOOGLE api key of visitor directly from BROWSER?

Tags: c#, google-translate

Well, I am trying to distribute free software (C#), which uses GOOGLE-TRANSLATE. ( However, it needs API CREDENTIALS in order to work).

I cant disribute MY API key in application. So can I program my application, as it opened `translate.google.com` and get "visitor" api key for each individual user itself?

I've seen application in the past doing that.

Comment: Authorization Code Grant Flow : https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

Answer (score 3):

Instead you should create a request for the key at the start of the program and then store the key in some config file.

If there is no key stored in the config file, prompt the user to add their key and give them instructions on getting a key from Google.